# Joining a table, but ensuring all rows from first table are returned

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a system for storing postal information in PostgreSQL. We have a `postal_carriers` table, that details carrier information. We have a `postal_zones` table that holds zones for `postal_carriers`. We have a `countries` table holding country information. I've now created a `postal_zone_mapping` table, that maps countries to zones of different carriers. Here is the definition for this.

```
CREATE TABLE shopman.postal_zone_mapping
(
    postal_zone_id integer,
    postal_carrier_id integer,
    country_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT pzm_key UNIQUE (country_id, postal_carrier_id),
    CONSTRAINT pzm_fkey FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
        REFERENCES shopman.countries (country_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT postal_zone_mapping_postal_carrier_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (postal_carrier_id)
        REFERENCES shopman.postal_carriers (postal_carrier_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT postal_zone_mapping_postal_zone_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (postal_zone_id)
        REFERENCES shopman.postal_zones (postal_zone_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

This is the statement I am using to select the data, selecting the `country` table with a left join on the `postal_zone_mapping` table, as I want all the countries listed for a carrier, whether they're mapped to a particular carrier and zone or not.

```
    SELECT c.country_id,
           COALESCE(postal_zone_id,-1) AS postal_zone_id,
           COALESCE(postal_carrier_id,-1) AS postal_carrier_id,
           country_name
      FROM shopman.countries c 
           LEFT JOIN shopman.postal_zone_mapping p 
                  ON c.country_id=p.country_id
     WHERE postal_carrier_id=1 
        OR postal_carrier_id IS NULL 
     ORDER BY country_name ASC 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
```

I want this query to return every country, a carrier ID if it matches the one we want along with zone id, but with my query, if we insert a map for a carrier, then the results returned do not have this country. Where am I going wrong with my query? Also, is there a better way to achieve this mapping? I went down this route to avoid having to dynamically add columns or have arrays.

Many thanks

For reference, here is the definition of the other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE shopman.postal_carriers
(
    postal_carrier_id serial,
    postal_carrier_name text,
    description text,
    CONSTRAINT postal_carriers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (postal_carrier_id),
    CONSTRAINT postal_carriers_postal_carrier_name_key UNIQUE (postal_carrier_name)
)

CREATE TABLE shopman.postal_zones
(
    postal_zone_id serial,
    postal_carrier_id integer,
    postal_zone_name text,
    CONSTRAINT postal_zones_pkey PRIMARY KEY (postal_zone_id),
    CONSTRAINT postal_zones_postal_zones_name_key UNIQUE (postal_carrier_id, postal_zone_name),
    CONSTRAINT postal_zones_postal_carrier_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (postal_carrier_id)
        REFERENCES shopman.postal_carriers (postal_carrier_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE shopman.countries
(
    country_id serial,
    country_name text,
    code_2 text",
    code_3 text,
    region_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT countries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (country_id),
    CONSTRAINT countries_code_2_key UNIQUE (code_2),
    CONSTRAINT countries_code_3_key UNIQUE (code_3),
    CONSTRAINT countries_name_key UNIQUE (country_name),
    CONSTRAINT countries_region_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (region_id)
        REFERENCES shopman.regions (region_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Hmm, if the zones are supposed to be something like ZIP code areas, I'd put the reference to the country in the zones table, not in the mapping table. Having the reference in the mapping table can lead to one zone having one country (for one carrier) and another country (for another carrier), which seems wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the condition on the *second* table into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.country_id,
       COALESCE(p.postal_zone_id, -1) AS postal_zone_id,
       COALESCE(p.postal_carrier_id,-1) AS postal_carrier_id,
       c.country_name
FROM shopman.countries c LEFT JOIN
     shopman.postal_zone_mapping p 
     ON c.country_id = p.country_id AND p.postal_carrier_id = 1 
ORDER BY c.country_name ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Perfect, it works as expected, thank you. Going to review using multiple conditions in ON statements to make sure I fully understand what's going on.